# WiFi Access Point Monitor mode

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Can i set WiFi AP to **Monitor mode** ?

- The AP have LAN connector only, not USB

[[ Picture of device ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x0NT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The (somewhat blurry) model number on your photo seems to be TL-WA7510N. Looking on the [Open WRT page](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa7510n) for it, WLAN is an Atheros AR9280 chip, and the `ath9k` driver [supports](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ath9k) monitor mode.

So yes, you can (even additionally) enable monitor mode, but you'll either have to get root access for the existing firmware, or install an open source firmware like OpenWRT.

Note that this device is **5 GHz only** (no 802.11 b/g/n on 2.4 GHz), and it's an **outdoor** access point (which you may or may not need).

Comment: OP should also note that this AP only supports a single radio chain (not MIMO), so if sniffing other networks' traffic, it won't be able to see any transmissions that use more than one spatial stream. It's also a/n, so it won't be able to see 802.11ac transmissions (i.e. ones that use 256-QAM).